# Getting refresh token after password reset in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

New users are on-boarded via an offline process. At the end they are directed to a custom policy that does a password reset. This allows the user to choose their own password.

This is essentially the standard custom password reset policy without the need to validate the email. The user name is passed via a signed JWT token.

This all works and a valid ID token is returned.

The problem is getting a refresh token when this token expires.

We haven't found a way to do this.

Setting an "offline_access" scope doesn't seem to do anything.

Trying the "silent refresh" approach (prompt = "none") returns an error message stating that you don't have a session.

The applications are SPA built around adal.js.

An example of the password reset message is:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?p=B2C_1A_Custom-PasswordReset
&client_id=xxx
&redirect_uri=yyy
&scope=openid%20offline_access&response_type=id_token
&prompt=login
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=JWT

Anyone ever got this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single-page application, a refresh token isn't issued, since this isn't considered to be secure.

Applications that use the implicit flow must implement [a silent authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa#refresh-tokens) to refresh tokens.

The silent authentication might be failing because your "Custom-PasswordReset" journey doesn't include [the **DefaultSSOSessionProvider** SSO session provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sso-custom#defaultssosessionprovider) to set the SSO claims in the user session.

As an example of this, see [the **LocalAccount-PasswordSet** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L2725) in the Wingtip sample, which is invoked to set the first-time password for a pre-verified user.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I followed the first part but will try the SSO session stuff. I was looking at "IncludeInSso" but that always seems to be set to "false". I couldn't find any documentation on that? Any idea what it does?

Comment: Hi @nzpcmad. `<IncludeInSso />` determined whether a technical profile should interact with the single sign-on (SSO) behavior; however, **it has been deprecated** in favour of `<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement />`.